# Xlsxwriter conditional formatting with whole rows

Tags: criteria, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I used the conditional formatting to set the background color with total amount rows

```
worksheet.conditional_format('B1:P%d' % (number_rows),
                                 {'type': 'formula',
                                  'criteria':'=INDIRECT("G"&ROW())=*Total*',
                                  'format': format2})
```

As the cell names are different but all of them contains "Total"
I don't know how to write the code about containing in 'criteria', above code did not work
The name like:3.2 Training costs Total
3.3 Travelling costs Total

Comment: Before using a conditional format with XlsxWriter you should figure out how to do it in Excel and then transfer it over to you program.